# Android : Repeating background stops repeating on rotation

Tags: android, background, rotation

my problem is following : On rotation, my background which is made of repeating pattern changes so that the pattern is stretched instead of repeating. What could possibly be wrong ?

I have this background made of repeating pattern:

`< bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />`

Comment: Do you have different layouts for different screen orientation?

Comment: yes I have. I've solved this one though. It was caused because of a bug in pre-ICS sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set repeating pattern manually :

```
parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.log_parent);
    Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pattern);
    BitmapDrawable patternRepeat = new BitmapDrawable(bg);
    patternRepeat.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    patternRepeat.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(patternRepeat);
```